# Universal Actions not showing in Gmail Addon in Phone

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons, google-apps-script-addon

I made a gmail addon, its working on web as well as Gmail app, but I am not getting universal actions in the Gmail app. It is coming in other apps (attached the screenshot of slack).

[Universal Actions of my slack's Gmail addon is showing in gmail app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO0Vz.png)

[Universal Actions of my addon not showing in gmail app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mbn9M.png)

[Universal Actions of my addon not showing in gmail web.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdu39.png)